# How to call $location in AngularJS in HTML With parameters

Tags: angularjs

I have a select list:

```
<select name="forma" onchange="location = Category(SCID: this.value)">
     <option value="38">Home</option>
     <option value="39">Contact</option>
     <option value="40">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

On selecting a option i want to make it equivalent to http://localhost/#/Category/38/.

How to do that?

i tried this: location = Category(SCID: this.value)

But its giving error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to write the code inline and change the location. My advise to you is don't.

When having the option of calling a function and writing javascript code inline, go for calling a function. It keeps your code clean, easier to understand and easier to maintain.

Thus, in this case, attach a model to you select so that when the user selects a value, you know which value the user has selected:

```
<select name="forma" data-ng-model="selectedFormaValue" 
        data-ng-change="updateLocation()">
     <option value="38">Home</option>
     <option value="39">Contact</option>
     <option value="40">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

Notice that I have attached a `ng-change` directive which calls the function `updateLocation()` when the select value changes.

Your `updateLocation()` function should look like:

```
$scope.updateLocation = function () {
    //Make sure that a value is selected
    if ($scope.selectedFormaValue) {
        $location.path('/Category/' + $scope.selectedFormaValue);
    }
};
```

This will cause the page to go to the location `http://locahost/#!/Category/<SelectedValue>`

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response. One more thing how to go to location: http://localhost/#/Category/<Selectedvalue>/  instead of http://locahost/#!/Category/<SelectedValue>

Comment: The `#!` depends on your route configuration. You can set `html5mode` to true or specify your own hashbang equivalent. Google "angularjs html5mode" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any onchange attribute to select directive in angularjs. You can use ngChange as stated by callmekatootie. You can try to do it inline as you are doing it now, or you can bind it to a scope function in controller. You should always delgate dom manipulations to controller which inturns changes the model. Hope this helps.